# How to put an array of bindless images into ubo

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I already have an ubo:

```
layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform view_shared_data {
    uniform int matrixIndex;
    uniform int projectionIndex;
    uniform uint set_only_input_id;
    uniform Matrices[MAX_MATRICES] matrices;
};
```

I am trying to add an array of bindless images to the ubo:

```
layout(bindless_image, r32ui) coherent uniform uimage2D[MAX_MATRICES] id_texture;
```

I will only write to the images using imageAtomicMax().

This compiles fine on windows using nvida gpu, but not on linux using amd. I am assuming something is wrong with my bindless_image, r32ui and coherent qualifiers, but I'm not sure how to set them correctly.

Comment: "*I am trying to add an array of bindless images to the ubo:*" How is that associated with `view_shared_data`? That's a uniform variable, not a member of the uniform block.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to put bindless images/samplers in a uniform block, you have to actually put them *inside* the block definition. Just like any other variable:

```
layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform view_shared_data {
    uniform int matrixIndex;
    uniform int projectionIndex;
    uniform uint set_only_input_id;
    uniform Matrices[MAX_MATRICES] matrices;
    layout(r32ui) coherent uimage2D[MAX_MATRICES] id_texture;
};
```

Each opaque type in a buffer-backed interface block is a single 64-bit integer. As such, the array stride of `id_texture` is 8-bytes, which matches a C or C++ array of 64-bit integers.

Comment: I have tried what you said, still works on nvidia, on amd I get: "error: memory qualifiers may only be applied in the declarations of image variables, buffer variables and shader storage blocks"